# RCP application is not able to access an api which is built in Java 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on RCP application and I need to access an api which is built in Java 1.8.
I have added the dependencies of that api in my application(I am using maven).

Actually I want to access that api and print response got from that api in my RCP application console window.

When I launch application using MyRCPApplication.product file from eclipse, it is able to access that api and prints the response in console window of RCP application.

But when I build my same application from outside of eclipse(mvn clean install) and try to run MyRCPApplication.exe then nothing is printed in console window of RCP application(even no error is printed!!).

What would be the reason for working from eclipse and not working outside of eclipse?

Could you please help me with the same? It would be very helpful for me.

Thanks In Advance!!

Execution Environment used in RCP application : JavaSE-1.7

Comment: If you are using Java 8 features you need to use JavaSE-1.8 as the execution environment. Other than that there isn't enough info here to be able to help.

Comment: Thank You for your response..having issues while using other eclipse(kepler and luna for rcp developers) which is having javaSE-1.8 execution environment while accessing target platform from nexus(earlier I was using eclipse helios in which JavaSE-1.7 is available)

Comment: Note that since Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09) Java 11 is required.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this issue.

I have changed my `JRE` which is going with **final executable**. Earlier I was using `Java7` to go with final executable, now I have **changed to `Java8` and resolved issue**.